# std::lock_guard and std::adopt_lock behaviour without locking the mutex

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been learning about the usage of `std::lock` and `std::lock_guard` and most examples follow the pattern below:

```
std::lock(m1, m2);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(m1, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(m2, std::adopt_lock);
//Do something here
```

Then I came across an example that utilized the same pattern you would use if you were using `std::unique_lock`, but with `lock_guard`:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard1(m1, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard2(m2, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock(m1, m2);
//Do something here
```

My question is, would this cause undefined behaviour if you use the second pattern and an exception occurs before you reach `std::lock`?

P.S. I am aware that C++17 introduced `std::scoped_lock` and that `std::lock_guard` is still around mainly for compatibility with older code.

Comment: I don't understand how the second pattern can be correct at all, regardless of any exceptions.  If `m1` and `m2` aren't held on entry to this code, then `adopt_lock` causes UB.  And if they are held, then `std::lock(m1, m2)` is UB, as you can't lock a mutex that you already hold.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Lockguard will trigger unlock in destructor on the mutex that isn't locked. Not 100% if it is UB or just implementation defined error. MSVC will trigger exception and subsequently terminate as that's what exceptions do in destructors.

Comment: @NateEldredge `adapt_lock` is a kind of NOOP for lockguard. The issue is with the destructor trigerring unlock.

Comment: @ALX23z: C++20 thread.lock.guard p4: `lock_guard(mutex_type& m, adopt_lock_t);` "Preconditions: The calling thread owns the mutex m."

Comment: _"...The __behavior is undefined__ if the current thread does not hold a non-shared lock..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard  Pattern (2) is UB regardless of exceptions.

Comment: @NateEldredge this isn't a true UB. It isn't like integer overflow where compiler can optimize it into something weird. It is more of a technical specification allowing library implementers to add asserts or whatever. It's not like implementation can add anything beyond checks `owns_lock` when the method exists. The purpose of stating that it is UB is say that it isn't allowed to do and not something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is undefined behavior; `adopt_lock` constructor presumes that the mutex is already held.  This UB is triggered at construction, not at destruction or when an exception is thrown.

---

If you used `unique_lock` instead of `scoped_lock`, it has a:

```
unique_lock( mutex_type& m, std::defer_lock_t t ) noexcept;
```

constructor, which permits your `std::lock` use with a slight change:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard1(m1, std::defer_lock);
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard2(m2, std::defer_lock);
std::lock(guard1, guard2);
```

Now, `unique_lock` does track if it has the lock, so there is possible memory and performance overhead; if `unique_lock`s are local to the scope, compilers can and will optimize out that if it can prove it safe.

And if the compiler can't prove it safe, quite often it isn't safe.